# Why does Vim cursor jump to selected text when bypassing visual mode?

Tags: vim

Vim automatic visual mode can be annoying. It's switching into visual mode when ever you left click and select a text in it. Fortunately there is the possibility to bypass this behaviour by holding shift-key while selecting text in the terminal. This bypass is useful, quickly to use at hand without having to configure vim first.

However I recently noticed that, when the terminal detects something as a link (for instance /var/www/example.com/ directory in apache vhost configs), and I try to select it using mouse+shift-key combination, it doesn't let me copy the selected text but jumps to the next similar line in the text while enabling auto visual mode again.

Why does this happen and how can I bypass that?

PS: I know about :set mouse-=a in vimrc but as I am working on different servers I don't want to have to edit vimrc each time I am on a new server.

Answer (score 1):

The only text-selection vim has is visual mode. So you tell vim with `mouse=a` that it should use the mouse to select text. What do you expect?

You could always copy the text without your mouse at all (`"+yy` if you have clipboard support).

I could not reproduce your behavior with the links. Is this also happening without plugins?

But anyway, if you don't want visual mode on your mouse, you have to modify the `mouse` setting and stop telling vim to use visual mode on your mouse.

Comment: I didn't want to use text-selection in Vim, I wanted to use the text selection of the terminal, which is blocked when Vim catches the mouse click event. Holding shift bypasses that behaviour, which always works except when the terminal detects a link in a line of text.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But `mouse=a` tells vim explicitly to use the text-selection. It is like saying, I don't want a blue car, but i only order blue cars, what should I do? Well the answer will always be, don't order blue cars. Whatever reason you have to not wanting to do that, the best solution will always be to unset `a` in the `mouse` setting.


Is the link detection a function of your terminal? Who/What does the link detection? I don't know any function in vim which would do that, so it is hard to help...

Comment: I did not order blue cars. mouse=a is default setting of Vim in my vanilla debian installation. I have to use set mouse-=a to disable it on every box. That's why I want to use shift+mouse for selecting text on machines I only seldom work on and only do a few quick edits so I don't want to install/configure a vimrc on each box. The link detection happens in xfce terminal and a few others I used over the years. When you click on it (w/o Vim) it opens the link in default browser.

Comment: I know that `mouse=a` seems to be the default behavior (why on earth... but that's another discussion). But it would be the correct way to change it anyway. However I see your point. But you still can copy the text with the keyboard (that's after all one of the reasons for vim). Have you tried to use `shift+mouse_left` and `shift+mouse_right` before and after the link? does that also jump? Else you will have to deactivate/remap the function in your terminal

Comment: Yes the strange thing is that it jumps to the other line no matter where I click. I can select `DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/` using shift+mouse then I shift+right click over DoumentRoot it jumps to the next occurence of DocumentRoot... Maybe it's a bug that happens somehow in combination with terminal functionality and Vim.

Comment: try starting vim with `vim -u NONE` then `:set mouse=a` and then try it again. Does it still happen?

Answer (score 0):

If there's a specific setting that you want on your main machine, but not on other servers etc then you can use an `if` statement in your `.vimrc` to specify which system you want the setting to be active on. For instance:

```
"My Linux machine
if readf('/etc/machine-id') == ['your-machine-id']
    set mouse=a
endif

"Only on Macs
if system('uname') == "Darwin\n"
    set mouse=a
endif
```

Comment: No, I didn't want machine specific settings. Vim by default switches to visual mode when I click into the terminal window. I can disable that with set mouse-=a or I can hold shift when selecting text, in that case the terminal window text selection and clipboard works. I don't want to have to configure vimrc on every server each time I just want to c&p a line thus I use shift+mouse select for quick edits. On my local machine I have auto visual mode completely off.

Comment: That's what I'm saying... you can set a setting for just your machine and any other machine/server can have `mouse-=a` by using a machine specific setting.

Comment: Yes but my point was, that I don't want to have to do that. I am using Vim there for quick edits sometime the servers are even just short living. It are a few machines and I don't want to have to configure it each time. That's why I use shift+mouse select, which always works well, except when the terminal detects a line containing a link.

Comment: You don't have to configure it each time. Just configure a generic setting for any computer that's not your own. Or any computer that's a Linux server or whatever. I'm not sure what other option you're looking for if you want it to work sometimes but not others?

Comment: When I connect to a server with ssh to edit a config file there, I am not using my local vimrc.

Comment: that may be worth a look: https://serverfault.com/questions/33423/how-to-bring-vimrc-around-when-i-ssh

Answer (score 0):

Someone is setting `mouse=a`. You can find the guilty one by executing `:verbose set mouse`.

Then you either have to change that or you have to create a .vimrc for your user. As far as I understand that might not be easy in your situation.

Instead of `set mouse-=a` you could also use `set mouse=` to disable all mouse stuff. This is what I prefer and it saves two keystrokes :-).

---

This is how I handle this problem. It might or might not be doable for you.

I have one file called `.rks`, that I scp to every server I have to login. 
The first command after login is always

```
. ./.rks
```

This sets up my shell environment (prompt, aliases, vi editing mode etc) and creates a file
called `~/.vimrc.rks` (if it doesn't exist) containing my basic Vim setup
(e.g. `set mouse=`). Finally it exports the variable `VIMINIT`:

```
export VIMINIT="source $HOME/.vimrc.rks"
```

Now Vim sources `~/.vimrc.rks` on startup and I get my setup.

This way I

- only have to transfer one file to all machines. Other files (like
  `.vimrc.rks`) are created when sourcing that file.
- have my personal setup without changing any default files. Others might also log in with the same user name.

---

I just learned, that I could automate the transfer of my setup file using ssh `LocalCommand` configuration. See this [answer on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/693842).